# Check background color in Selenium Ide

Tags: html, selenium-ide

This is my code html :

```
<td class = "en" style = "background-color= #0000FF">
```

I now want to check the color in selenium:

```
Command: verifyAttribute

Target : style

Value  : background-color= #0000FF
```

After checking I get the answer: `error-style not found`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed wild card, Try :

```
command: verifyAttribute

Target : css=td#my_div@style

value  : *background-color= #0000FF*
```

Change your td to:

```
<td id="my_div" class = "en" style = "background-color= #0000FF">
```

Comment: I tried this and continue the same message: Error styles not found. Help